# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico' in Terminal

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am building blog app. AND i am using Django Version :- 3.8.1. AND i am stuck on an Error.

views.py

```
def detail_view(request,id):
    id = int(id)
    data = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)

    context = {'data':data,}
    return render(request, 'show_more.html', context )
```

urls.py

```
path('<id>',views.detail_view,name='detail_view'),
```

show_more.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load post_tags %}



<br>
<a>Posted at - {{ data.date_added }}</a>
<br>

<br>
  <a>{{ data.blog_post_title }}</a>
  <br>
```

**Error**

When i start server. Everything is working Fine. Every page is opening fine, BUT when i see the terminal then It is showing `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico'` in terminal at every page i Click in Browser.

Any help would be Appreciated . Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Can you include the template which links to `detail_view`? The error appears to come from within `detail_view` due to the value that's provided as the `id` so likely comes from a template different to that which you've included.

Answer (score 1):

try this

int:section matches a string of decimal digits and converts the value to an int.

```
path('<int:id>',views.detail_view,name='detail_view'),
```

refer this --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/

Comment: Now it is showing :- `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'.`

Comment: @developer you cannot pass a string to get data using id. you need pass numbet

Comment: I have uploaded the template.